# What are problems with shallow copy?

Tags: c++, shallow-copy

This is an interview question I saw from here:
http://www.careercup.com/question?id=1707701

Want to know more about this .thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shallow copy causes a problem (primarily) when you have "remote ownership". The most common form is a pointer to data that's owned by the object so when the object is destroyed the data it owns gets destroyed as well. One place many people run into this is the inevitable  string class:

```
// warning: bad code. Do *not* use.
class mystring { 
    char *data;
public:
    mystring() : data(NULL) {}
    mystring(char *init) {
        data = new char[strlen(init)+1];
        strcpy(data, init);
    }

    ~mystring() { delete [] data; }
};

int main() { 
     mystring s("This is a string");

     mystring t;

     t = s;
}
```

This will compile just fine. Under these *exact* circumstances, it *might* even seem to run fine as well. That doesn't mean it's really right though. When we assign `s` to `t`, the *pointer* gets copied, but what it points at does not get copied. We have *two* objects both containing pointers to the same buffer. When one of them gets destroyed, it deletes the associated buffer for the data. Then we have a dangling pointer -- it's still trying to refer to the buffer, but the buffer no longer exists. When the second object gets destroyed, it'll try to free the same memory again -- but since it's already been freed, that leads to undefined behavior (I.e., anything can happen, and something bad usually will).

There are two common alternatives to shallow copying. One is a "deep" copy, in which we overload the copy constructor and assignment operator for the class, and in them when we copy/assign the object, we allocate a new buffer and copy the contents of the old buffer to the new one.

The second is reference counting. Instead of a "raw" pointer to the buffer, we use a "smart" pointer to the buffer. The smart pointer keeps track of how many objects refer to the buffer and only frees the buffer itself when nothing refers to it any more.

Neither is entirely perfect: deep copying can be slow and use a lot of memory, especially if there's a lot of data involved. Reference counting can be slow in multi-threaded environments -- since the reference count can be accessed from multiple threads, you have to protect it to assure only one thread modifies it a time (which is usually at least an order of magnitude slower than a normal increment/decrement).

Comment: very clear post. Thank you Jerry.

Answer (score 4):

shallow copy is when you just make a copy of an object with exactly the same fields(and pointer):

the class

```
class Car{
String name;
Owner* owner;
}
```

arguments:

```
Owner owner
Car car1 = {"car", owner}
Car car2 = car1.copy
car2 = {"car", owner}
```

so now we copied all fields of car1 to car2 and both of them fields owner pointing to same owner, and since owner it's a pointer we are now have a dangling pointer so each change made in car1 will affect car2

but if we would made a deep copy we should get it right:

```
Car car3 = car1.deepCopy => will create ownerCopy = owner.copy
car3 = {"car", ownerCopy}
```

so now changes on car1 won't affect car3 at all

[HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) is an explanation with images

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) has a good introduction